# Why does our g-suite marketplace installed app not get the appropriate scopes?

Tags: google-workspace, google-apps-marketplace, google-classroom

We published our app via the G-Suite marketplace.

Admins can install the app domain-wide for users to access and they are asked at that time to approve all the scopes our application needs.

When users in an domain where the app is installed try to use features that integrate with Google - specifically fetching classroom data - they are not prompted to give us access to the data we request and yet the scopes are not requested from that user.

If the user does NOT have the marketplace app installed on their domain, they are simply prompted to grant access to the data and can continue.

To workaround this we removed all the requested scopes from the marketplace listing, and now users in a domain with the app installed are asked to approve scopes individually when we request them.

However, the G-Suite marketplace documentation specifically says that we are supposed to avoid having to ask users individually to grant scopes, so this seems wrong.

Has anyone else run into this issue and found a solution?

Comment: Hi, have you found a fix for this issue? it seems that it still runs. I had the same problem with an app.

Comment: To workaround it, we removed all scopes from the marketplace listing.  In this case, the user has to approve the scopes manually, which isn't how it's supposed to work but better than having them silently not granted.

Comment: It has come to my attention that there's an issue tracker for G Suite Marketplace so I've opened an issue there: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/141191495

Comment: In my case I found it was a problem with the gapi javascript api. When I ask for the extra scopes they are not granted when the app is installed for the domain. But they are if a user installs it individually. 

The fix was to set the scopes at the very first init of gapi.auth2 by adding these lines:

```<meta name="google-signin-client_id" content="17*****9-t*****e.apps.googleusercontent.com">
<meta name="google-signin-scope" content="EXTRA SCOPES">```


just before loading the api:
```< script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js"></ script >```

Comment: Interesting.  I seems like for users not part of a domain we are supposed to ask for scopes only on an as-needed basis.  Is it then the case that for apps installed via G-Suite Marketplace we have to ask for all scopes up-front?